# Save user acquisition source and medium - organic, paid, referral site, etc

Tags: php, google-analytics, statistics, analytics

When a user signs up, I'd like to store how they got there. I'm using Google analytics.js for analytics and am using php on the back end.

This will come in handy when the user upgrades his or her account later on. Metrics heaven for a subscription based website.

Comment: Google doesn't offer an API to do that. Your best option is to skip Google Analytics and calculate that yourself using `document.referrer`.

Answer (score 0):

**coderMatt**, source/medium information is no longer stored in cookie, so you can't access that information directly.